# Posibles combinaciones de un arreglo numérico hasta tener una suma igual al resultado requerido

Tags: php, php7

Estoy tratando de diseñar una calculadora basada en un arreglo numérico (números digitados de manera manual), y no encuentro una manera optima de hacerla sin hardcodear con for anidados XD:

la idea es tener todos los valores (unos 20) y buscar combinaciones de estos números que sumados den como resultado el valor requerido ejemplo:

```
$valores = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$requerido = 14;

resultado: 5+4+3+2
```

Me interesa recorrer a $valores, para encontrar las combinaciones; 
ejemplo {A,B,C,D}

combinaciones posibles:

```
A,B,C,D,AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD,ABC,ABD,ACD,BCD,ABCD
```

Destaco que combinaciones como BA no son requeridas ya que para obtener el resultado requerido ($requerido) la combinación `((A+B===B+A) ó (AB===BA)`

Espero haberme explicado adecuadamente. XD

Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Suena interesante, sin embargo, no sé qué tan razonable sea tu propuesta. Lo que quieres es todas las posibles combinaciones (sin repetición) de *P* elementos, escogidos de *N* elementos, (*P* y *N* enteros) tal que *P <= N* y donde se cumpla que la suma *P[i] = k*, con k entero dado.

Comment: Matemáticamente hablando y si lo entendí adecuadamente es exactamente lo que indicas. Gracias por la aclaración @MauricioContreras

Comment: No será fácil de implementar al principio, pero se puede realizar. ¿Has intentado algo? Si tienes algo que hayas probado, así te parezca incompleto o que no tenga sentido puedes subirlo. Saludos

Comment: "No será fácil", no lo ha sido XD. Inicialmente trate de hacerlo utilizando foreach anidados pero luego encontré este [caso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array), es parecido pero basado en string y las combinaciones si se pueden repetir. ahora estoy buscando alguna lógica  en base a este código.

Comment: El problema que afrontas, usando lo que has planteado, es la cantidad de combinaciones que debes probar para obtener un resultado. Las [combinaciones sin repetición](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatoria#Combinaciones_sin_repetici%C3%B3n) para la cantidad de elementos que planteas, supone un alto costo computacional. Ya que debes probar combinaciones de grupos desde 1 hasta 20 elementos. Para darte una idea, el valor de *Cnr(20,10)* es 184756, esto significa que sólo para descartar la combinación de grupos de 10 elementos debes realizar más de 184 mil comprobaciones.

Comment: Según la información que me suministraste he investigado algo extra y hecho "for" anidados que hagan lo que deseo. El cálculo total corresponde con 1,047,335 combinaciones distintas a probar para 20 elementos. con "for" anidados mi computador tardo unos 15 segundos. Gracias a esto he retomado y es posible que me encuentre cerca de la solución. En conclusión, el gasto computacional (en mi caso) no es tanto debido a que no se repiten lo términos. En cuanto tenga la solución la publicaré para la comunidad. Gracias @Mauricio Contreras

Comment: Entiendo que 15 segundos te parezcan pocos, el algoritmo realiza más de 1 millón de comprobaciones en ese tiempo. Sin embargo, yo mantengo que no es óptimo y tampoco razonable. Aún así con un array de 20 números diferentes, por más granularidad de los datos, hay un límite en la cantidad máxima a la cual le puedes hallar una combinación que pertenezca a tu conjunto. Sigo insistiendo que debe haber una forma diferente de hacerlo. Hablamos de la deconstrucción en sumandos de un número.